# Blender mesh shape to Illustrator

Tags: mesh

I've created a shape object with mesh. It's a side of a POS stand. I need to create sheet cuts for printing purposes. How can i export mesh shape to svg or other vector file ?

Comment: Thanks for tip. That's a nice idea with addon, but i have just figured it out by myself, just with another way.

1. Select mesh, go to Edit mode
2. Select shape
3. Unwrap, Project from view
4. In UV/Image Editor, select unwrapped shape
5. UVs -> Export UV Layout -> SVG

Comment: Clever! I didn't know you could export UVs to SVG.. Learn something new every day ;)

Comment: There are options available: PNG/EPS/SVG :)

Comment: @Evanduril Please add that as an answer using the answer box below.

Comment: Sorry, i don't see any button or box that would allow me to mark this thread as answered.